# How to fix Authentication Plugin error for dBeaver

Tags: mysql, dbeaver, sha2

I am getting the following error while trying to connect to a database from dBeaver.

[image: DBeaver error]

This has to be a dBeaver issue as I am able to connect via the command line successfully.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to check if dbeaver supports this authentication method in a newer version. If not, then you need to change the authentication method for that user or use a different mysql client. You can check dbeaver documentation for the former and find the answer for the latter here on SO.

Comment: @Shadow it will not be possible to change the authentication method for that user. Any idea what other mysql client I should use?

Comment: Sorry, recommending products are off topic here on SO because recommendations are inherently opinion based. I think you should take a look at them and evaluate yourself.

Comment: Alright. Thanks!